# Java прерывание потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность, сокет

Интересует, как реагирует поток, который закрывается извне, если он содержит работу с сокетной системой, а именно: Закрываются ли сокеты и стирается ли информация о них, если поток закрывается извне с помощью функций `.stop()` или `.interrupt()`?

Answer (score 1):

`ThreadDeath`, провоцируемый методом `stop()` никакие захваченные потоком ресурсы, не освобождает, только мониторы.

Крайне не рекомендуется останавливать потоки методом `stop()`, это работает, однако, все мониторы, которые были захвачены в этом потоке (секции кода, обёрнутые `synchronized`), будут отпущены, что в свою очередь может привести к не консистентному состоянию приложения.

`interrupt()` же устанавливает внутренний флаг, который вы можете проверить внутри вашего потока, все правильно закрыть и завершить выполнение.

Для этого у потока есть метод `isInterrupted()` он проверяет флаг прерывания у потока. При этом сам флаг не сбрасывается.

Так же есть метод `interrupted()` он проверяет был ли установлен флаг прерывания у текущего потока. При этом флаг прерывания после вызова этого метода сбрасывается.